# Apportable game stuck on splash screen indie version and no app icon

Tags: apportable

Im facing an issue the details are below

1. I use the free starter version and make my game running on android, it was a successful experience expect I was having some performance and touches issues.
2. I then go for indie trial version to see it those issues are solved.
3. The code successly compiles with indie version and an apk is made. But when i run apk (load) there is no icon on android device and the game is stuck on splash screen. The game is not going forward. It was working fine with starter version.

The following error appears on android logs

```
W/System.err( 5367): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getSource
W/System.err( 5367):    at com.apportable.MainThread.nativeRun(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5367):    at com.apportable.MainThread.access$100(MainThread.java:15)
W/System.err( 5367):    at com.apportable.MainThread$2.run(MainThread.java:79)
W/System.err( 5367):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/System.err( 5367):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err( 5367):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err( 5367):    at com.apportable.MainThread$1.run(MainThread.java:42)
W/System.err( 5367):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

In case of debug mode

```
Attaching to pid 6262
Cannot attach to lwp 6262: Operation not permitted (1)
Exiting
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For the debug issue, try uninstalling any old versions first - "apportable uninstall"

Comment: @PaulBeusterien thanks for post. I beleive i have found the problem. i was using starter pack where game works fine i then update to indie after which same code stops working to run on android. i uninstall and  install starter pack again and the code still doesnt work. I then install the starter pack on a different system and it works fine. so the issue is between updating Apportable sdk's where some configuration/settings/files mis-match and causes the issue.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien could you tell me what i need to do to remove completely Apportabe so that i can install the fresh update again to remove the above mentioned issue. i had tried "rm -rf ~/.apportable" and remove all the config files created inside the project but it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't get removed? In any case, it is unlikely that the issue is a fresh install versus an update install. We've confirmed there should be no difference. Likely, the issue is something else.

Comment: i have check it twice, when i update sdk from starter to indie the app stops working and even after unistalling and fresh install the app ddnt work. After this to make sure i make a new account on my macbook and have fresh install i ran the same code and it worked. what other are the possibilies ?